# Only show a subreport if it returns data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, subreport

I have a subreport in a tablix row that I want to only show if there is data, because when the subreport doesn't return anything, i get a blank line.  How can I fix this? I do not want that blank line to show.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Visibility` parameter of the subreport with an expression?

Comment: What would I put in that expression?

Comment: You would need some sort of indicator. Depending on your situation, you may be able to do a `Count` or `Sum` to determine of there's data at that level. If not, you could also calculate the indicator in the initial dataset based on a subquery that reflects the data in the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the gray block of the row and right click then go to 'Row Visibility' and from  there go to show or hide based on expression and your expression should look like:
    =Iif(IsNothing(Your Field.Value),True,False)